# Windows 10 (OS) - XAMPP with localhost - Oxwall software - Cron issues

Tags: cron, xampp, localhost, windows-10, oxwall

I know this may be a long shot targeting those here on stackoverflow who use oxwall software to help me with my question, but sadly, I've tried all other sources - even the oxwall forums but to no avail.

For starters - here is what I have so far:

- I'm currently running `Windows 10` as my OS
- I have `XAMPP` installed
- Control panel `Apache` and `MySQL` are activated or started/running
- Using `Localhost:100` instead of `Localhost:80` due to conflicts with other applications
- User: `root` with password left blank or empty
- I have the `Oxwall software - version 1.8.0` within my `htdocs` folder
- I have a `database` setup using mysql with it's current port set to `3306`

My issue:

**When installing the oxwall software and get to the third section in the installation process, I am unable to proceed due to setting up a cron job incorrectly.**

Due to the fact that I'm running on a `localhost` with my port as `100` - on a windows machine, using xampp - I'm pretty much clueless on how to get this cron job working correctly and/or even setup for that matter.

I've read literally all the topics that were discussed on the oxwall forums and even followed their `documentation` but still nothing.

The error I get is this:

**`ow_includes/config.php file is incorrect. Update it with details provided below.`**

However, the only details given states:

• Create a cron job that runs ow_cron/run.php once a minute. (?) - with the question mark directing me to the oxwall documentation of how to setup a cron job.  But that doesn't seem to work...

I'm literally at a loss here, I've tried to create a `.bat` file and created a `task schedule` but nothing...

Even if there is nobody here that uses Oxwall, I'm hoping this can still be answered.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message when using using Oxwall 1.8.1 on my own VPS with CentOS 7, PHP 5.5.31 and mariaDB 5.5.44.

I noticed that the DB only contained one table because my DB user does not have 'Lock table' rights. Once I added these rights to my DB user for Oxwall DB, removed the table and continued the installation, all tables were created and installation was successful.